# HTML multidimensional array post to Java

Tags: java, html

I have a html like this:

ROW1

```
<input type="text" name="identification[type]" />
<input type="text" name="identification[number]" />
```

ROW2

```
<input type="text" name="identification[type]" />
<input type="text" name="identification[number]" />
```

ROW3

```
<input type="text" name="identification[type]" />
<input type="text" name="identification[number]" />
```

and continue to ***n*** number of rows. This is to do an update, input field values populated based on the data from database.

How do I get the values of the identification. Each type in input tied to its own number.
I do know how to get a single dimensional array from HTML to Java. But the above, I face hard time to achieve it. This can be easily done in Laravel - PHP. But know I'm trying to use Java to get it. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I do have one solution to use identificationType and identificationNumber instead of using identification[type] and identification[number]

Comment: With java you mean JSF?

Comment: With servlet. Html send POST data to servlet

Comment: Nowadays, you normally would use JSON or XML for this purpose.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm working on existing project. So got to continue from how it is.

Comment: will your identification[type] and identification[number] will be in sequence, you mentioned that for each type there will be number corresponding to it. You can get both of them as array and iterate one by one by an index to get it in servlet.

Comment: yes it is brother.